# How to process aggregates in batch and publish only one event in DDD?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I run into a situation while developing my domain I hope someone can help me solve.

In my current project I need to read from a cache all the stored aggregates of one type (let's say ClientAggregate). I read the aggregates from the service layer and then, for each one of them, I acquire a lock for the current aggregate to do some processing and then save it back. The business logic requires that only one event is sent out with information about the modified aggregates because the system listening to this event is a legacy system and has a schema already defined.

The problem I have is that, because of this locking process, the event I send is sent from the service layer instead of the domain. The logic requires to send information of the aggregates that had been modified all together in one event. Because I need to lock aggregates individually for performance reasons, I cannot pass all the aggregates to a domain service to handle the logic from there and generate the event. My option here would be to lock directly from inside the domain service but then I'd leak infrastructure logic into my domain.

So, in my current solution, the service contains domain logic to iterate through the aggregates and generate the event. Doing it inside a domain service, the logic would be in the domain but the locking mechanism would need to be moved along. A third option would be to publish an event for each modified aggregate but then there should be something able to consume them all, waiting somehow for the whole process to finish, so I don't know if this is even an option.

Comment: Do you really need pessimistic locking? Anyway for batch processing of aggregates perhaps you should be looking into sagas.

Comment: The store is based only in the cache. If I don't lock it could happen that another thread removes something from the object the moment I'm trying to read it for this processing. 
I don't really get how to work with sagas and aggregates. What I know about sagas is that you have a coordinator who sends messages to the different services and in the end sends the commit confirmation or the compensation message in case there was an error. How do you work with this inside the same service to coordinate aggregates?

Answer (score 1):

> The business logic requires that only one event is sent out with information about the modified aggregates because the system listening to this event is a legacy system and has a schema already defined.

That doesn't sound like the event is a real domain event to me. If it was, the reason you are trying to build your system this way would be **because the domain works like that** and not "because the system listening to this event is a legacy system".

So what you should do is this:

- Control the whole batch processing from the service layer as you already have it.
- If the logic that processes each aggregate is domain logic, extract that into a domain service and call it from the service layer.
- That domain service may also publish domain events, **if the domain requires it**.
- Publish the "finished* event from the service layer when finished. This is **not** a domain event.

Comment: I'm not sure about the event not belonging to the domain. It's my first time dealing with changing a batch of aggregates so maybe that's why. The business logic requires that, given a specific event, all aggregates should be analysed to check if they match a certain criteria and then be updated. Then, an event should be sent with information about the aggregates modified. It's just that this event has to be transformed to match the legacy schema. My problem is with locking the aggregates. The domain should send the event but for that I would need to lock from inside the domain service.

Comment: If locking is a precondition to be able to send domain events, I'd say you have a more fundamental design issue. Why can't you just lock in the service layer and publish the event from the domain layer?

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I lock at the service and call the domain from inside the lock.but this is done for each aggregate individually as i may have 100000 records.i cannot lock all of them upfront as it would kill the application.but then, the one orchestrating is the service layer to keep track of the ones modified.to do this from the domain,i would need to lock from inside the domain service to keep track of changes.

Comment: So everything is where it belongs! Transaction control belongs in the service layer, so the "orchestration" is fine there.

Comment: Hmm, if I hadn't this locking problem I would send the message from the domain instead I think. To me, the one that should handle the call to each aggregate and send an event should be a domain service as it is specify this way in the requirements. Then, the one building the message for the legacy system based on this event should be an infrastructure listener consuming that event. But I cannot come to any other option so I guess this is as close to it as I can get. Thanks for the tips!